# Elasticsearch query with lookup table

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating ES database for analyzing the historical data. I have 2 types of the data. First the product:

```
{
 "id" : 3,
 "name" : "Great product name",
 "feature1" : "Custom feature",
 "feature2" : true,
 "idCategory" : 2
}
```

and a lot of historical data:

```
{
 "date" : "Apr 24, 2019 @ 23:59:59.000",
 "price" : 20.59
 "idStore" : 5
}
```

I query records to get, for example, in one date range for products in specific category, get per day top X stores and their count of historical data.

Firstly I combined this in one document and put in one index. It works great but the problem appears, when I want to change the category of a product, I have to update all the historical data.

Is there a way to join the tables and query both documents at once. 
I took a look about joins in ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html but I think there is not a nice, proper way to do this.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this not an option? I can't manage to understand from your description 
```{
 "id" : 3,
 "name" : "Great product name",
 "feature1" : "Custom feature",
 "feature2" : true,
 "idCategory" : 2,
 "prices":[{
 "date" : "Apr 24, 2019 @ 23:59:59.000",
 "price" : 20.59
 "idStore" : 5
}]
}```

Comment: I merged it to put same product multiple times (each has date, price, id, features,..). But in your case to have in subarray, I have to check the performance of it. Also there could be millions of records in subarray. Don't know if ES would like that.

Comment: The way that Elasticsearch handles an index (using inverted indices) should be very helpful in this case) You can also see some tips in this link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/performance-issue-when-searching-data-in-a-large-array/159182

Answer (score -1):

Re-reading your question I have just recalled on the `join` datatype https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/parent-join.html